# How to return more than one rows from subquery used as expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql

### bedroom_count is not a single row

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN p.property_type = 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' THEN
       (SELECT fp.bedroom_count
        FROM floor_plans fp
        WHERE fp.removed = FALSE
          AND fp.property_id = p.id)
     ELSE
       (SELECT pu.bedroom_count
        FROM property_units pu
        WHERE pu.removed = FALSE
          AND pu.property_id = p.id)
   END
 FROM properties p
 WHERE p.id = 550;
```

> I have this,bedroom_count is not a single row, so it gives this error
> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>
> **I need to get that result, in that case, is there any other solution for this?**

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What should the output look like? Maybe you are looking for a UNION. Or you are looking for a JOIN. Or maybe you want the `sum()` - but without more details on the problem you are trying to solve this can't be answered properly.

Comment: But what bedroom count would you want to select in case there are multiple matches? The maximum count? The minimum count? The average count? The sum of the counts? For all these there exist an aggregation function.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response result more than one row I have two cases under one case it should come from other table and the other the other one

Comment: there can't be multiple matches

Comment: it is either apartment_community or something other

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name.   https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner

Comment: No, you have misunderstood. I mean multiple matches in the subquery, i.e. multiple rows.  If ID 550 is of 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' and there are two floor_plans rows for this ID, one with a bedroom count of 10, one with a count of 20, which number do you want to show in your results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner.  ohhh okay that's the problem I want all of them as result

Comment: In order to address people use their name with an at sign @Grigor Martiros. Please edit your request and show some sample data and the expected result. And tag your request with your DBMS.

Comment: Hi thanks I already solved I will publish it in case someone needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  case 
            when p.property_type ='APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' 
                then (  
                    select  array_agg(distinct fp.bedroom_count) 
                    from    floor_plans fp 
                    where   fp.removed = false 
                    and     fp.property_id=p.id ) 
            else (
                    select  (array_agg(distinct pu.bedroom_count)) 
                    from    property_units pu 
                    where   pu.removed = false 
                    and pu.property_id=p.id ) 
        end 
from    properties p 
where   p.id =550
```

this is the answer to my problem in case someone needs it

Comment: Okay, so it is indeed an aggregation you were looking for. Next time you ask a question, please show sample data and expected result, so we understand what you are asking.

Comment: yeah sorry ,this is my first time )))) thanks a lot I will

Comment: I learnt a lot from your answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that either first or second subquery return more than 1 row for given property_id (550). From your comments

> I want all of them as result

I'm guessing that what you need is left join with both tables. Try this

```
select p.property_type, coalesce(fp.bedroom_count, pu.bedroom_count) as bedroom_count
  from properties p
  left join floor_plans fp 
    on p.property_type = 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' and fp.removed = false and fp.property_id = p.id
  left join property_units pu
    on p.property_type <> 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' and pu.removed = false and pu.property_id = p.id
 where p.id = 550
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really want to join the tables. As you want the bedroom counts from one table or the other, though, you would have to outer join the tables.

```
select p.*, coalesce(fp.bedroom_count, pu.bedroom_count) as bedroom_count
from properties p
left join floor_plans fp on p.property_type = 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' 
                         and fp.property_id = p.id
                         and fp.removed = false 
left join property_units pu on p.property_type <> 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY' 
                            and pu.property_id = p.id
                            and pu.removed = false 
where p.id = 550
order by p.id;
```

Or use `UNION ALL`:

```
select p.*, fp.bedroom_count
from properties p
join floor_plans fp on fp.property_id = p.id and fp.removed = false 
where p.id = 550
and p.property_type = 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY'
union all
select p.*, pu.bedroom_count
from properties p
join property_units pu on pu.property_id = p.id and pu.removed = false 
where p.id = 550
and p.property_type <> 'APARTMENT_COMMUNITY'
order by p.id;
```

(If property_type can be null, these queries will need some adjustment to deal with this.)